# Installing perl modules in [Windows Subsystem for Linux]

Tags: linux, perl, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use a Perl script in Linux environment under Windows 10 ([WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)). I have enabled WSL, installed compilers (`gcc` and `make`), executed `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. Perl is working and I can run simple scripts. Problems start when I try to install a perl module. For example, I was trying to add `LWP` by running `perl -MCPAN -e'install "LWP"'`. It gives lots of error/warning messages, starting with `Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:`. The full output is too big to paste it here, so I have to put it elsewhere: http://pastebin.com/RRRedwbG. In short, no matter the package, all the .pm and .t files are deemed to be missing.

Comment: Probably this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/186

Comment: yes! I've just found it as well

Comment: @VasilyA By the way, you can just do `cpan LWP`. No need to mess around with `perl -MCPAN -e ...`.

Comment: @melpomene oh, true. I missed that line.

Comment: following that github post, I've edited `/usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/Config.pm` to have `dont_use_nlink => 1,`, now it gives another error message. I will update my post now

Comment: @melpomene, Would you care to write up an answer?

Comment: @Vasily A, If you have a new problem, ask it as a new question.

Comment: @ikegami I don't feel competent enough for that. I've never used WSL, and according to the link the bug is closed, so I'm not sure what to recommend.

Comment: Finally it worked out! I've added an answer, will be grateful if someone can explain what does the last line (`eval`) do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution found at [github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/186](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/186#issuecomment-240591395):
1. run `sudo apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl cpanminus build-essential`
2. edit `/usr/lib/perl/5.18.2/Config.pm` (around line 94) to have `dont_use_nlink => 1`
3. `eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"`

Comment: That third command is for using local::lib, which is unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: The first command installs `local::lib`, `cpanm`, and some build tools (make, gcc, etc). It's not directly related either.

Comment: well, just editing `Config.pm` did not work for me, I only succeeded after running all three commands.

Comment: @VasilyA What error did you get after editing Config.pm?

Comment: You might need/want them for unrelated reasons.

Comment: The first command failed for me just now – `E: Unable to locate package ... liblocal-lib-perl ... cpanminus` for `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` (according to `sudo lsb_release -a`).

Answer (score 7):

On unix file systems, a directory's `.` is a hardlink to itself, and a directory's `..` is a hardlink to its parent directory. So when you `stat` a directory, the link count returned by `stat` will be at least `1 (name) + 1 (.) + $num_sub_dirs (..)`.

```
$ ls -ld .
drwx------ 5 ikegami ikegami 46 Dec 16 12:03 .    # 5 = Could have up to three subdirs

$ ls -l .
total 0
drwx------ 2 ikegami ikegami 10 Dec 16 12:03 a    # 2 = No subdirs
drwx------ 3 ikegami ikegami 24 Dec 16 12:03 b    # 3 = Could have up to one subdir
drwx------ 2 ikegami ikegami 10 Dec 16 12:03 c    # 2 = No subdirs
```

File::Find relies on that information to optimize itself when possible.

Perl and File::Find know this isn't the case for the FAT and NTFS file systems, so the optimization is disabled on Windows. However, VSL looks like a Linux system to them, so they incorrectly assume they are dealing with a unix file system.

The best fix is to edit the file named by the output of the following command:

```
perl -MConfig -e'CORE::say $INC{"Config.pm"}'
```

Change

```
dont_use_nlink => undef
```

to

```
dont_use_nlink => 1
```

You can verify the change using

```
$ perl -V:dont_use_nlink
dont_use_nlink='1';
```

---

This answer is based on [this bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/186).